# Linux LUKS encrypted root: fstrim always trims all empty space

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, trim

I have a Manjaro system with a LUKS encrypted root filesystem on an NVME SSD. It is set up to decrypt `/` on boot via the kernel.

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
initrd=\amd-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-5.11-x86_64.img root=UUID=</dev/mapper/cryptroot UUID> rw cryptdevice=UUID=<SSD partition UUID>:cryptroot:allow-discards

$ cat /etc/fstab
# /dev/mapper/cryptroot
UUID=</dev/mapper/cryptroot UUID>       /               xfs             rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota        0 0

# /dev/nvme0n1p1
UUID=</boot UUID>          /boot           vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 0
```

This all works, but recently I realised trim wasn't enabled. I added `:allow-discards` to the kernel command line as you can see above. Now, every time I run `fstrim -v /` it trims all of the free space even when there has been little filesystem activity:

```
$ sudo fstrim -v /
/: 540.8 GiB (580689911808 bytes) trimmed
$ sudo fstrim -v /
/: 540.8 GiB (580660371456 bytes) trimmed
```

Is this expected behaviour? My other SSDs (unencrypted) typically trim much less on an `fstrim`. `dmsetup table` shows the `allow_discards` option so trim should be enabled.

Comment: The output is filesystem-specific, like with f2fs it would always be `0` IIRC.

Comment: Ubuntu with encrypted ext4 root here. Subsequent trims are smaller, down to 0 bytes.

Comment: Also essentially, regardless of the output value, `fstrim` should always cause logical blocks that are not currently used by the filesystem to be discarded. The filesystem won't keep track of whether they are "fresh". (Well, I can't tell for sure if that's true for all filesystems.)